# Can't use delay on CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying a create a slideshow with some nice html. I've managed to create about 4 slides. But the fourth slide gets over the third slide. I've adjusted the delay time so it shows up later but it doesn't work. I'm using shorthand properties but I already tried without shorthand and it didn't work too.
My code below:

```
/*slide 4 */
    #slideInLeft4 {  /* do slide 4. Para criar de um terceiro, só copiar e colar, trocar os nomes para o número correspondente e alterar o delay*/
 -webkit-animation: slideInLeft4 20s 59s 1 normal both;  /* duração, atraso, repetição, direção, modo de preenchimento Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    slideInLeft4 20s 59s 1 normal both;  /* duração, atraso, repetição, direção, modo de preenchimento Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      slideInLeft4 20s 59s 1 normal both;  /* duração, atraso, repetição, direção, modo de preenchimento Opera 12+ */
  animation:         slideInLeft4 20s 59s 1 normal both;  /* duração, atraso, repetição, direção, modo de preenchimento IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
  }
  @keyframes slideInLeft4 {   /* a porcentagem representa a animation-duration. Exemplo: animation-duration: 10s, então 20% é 2s */
  0% {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 1;
  }
  10% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  95% { /* tempo que começa a desaparecer o slide */
  opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
  opacity: 0;
  }
  }
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielluz/kh2mp3b1/

Comment: My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielluz/kh2mp3b1/

Comment: Fiddle looks broken for me. Add the rest of the relevant code. Also the image is not working. Also, add the link to the fiddle to your question.

Comment: The animation shorthand looks weird, you should specify the easing function between duration and delay

Comment: Done that. Still doesn't work. Image and video get overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Shorthand parameters in the right order:

- animation-name (slideInLeft4)
- duration (20s)
- timing-function (Try linear or [look at those available](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp))
- **delay** (59s)
- iteration-count (1)
- direction (normal)
- fill-mode (both)
- play-state (useful with JS to play/stop it).

In your case, it should have been:

```
animation: slideInLeft4 20s linear 59s 1 normal both;
```

Source: [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Both slides get mixed. See my fiddle: jsfiddle.net/gabrielluz/kh2mp3b1

Comment: Delay is working as expected: you have a picture that just appears after 59s, takes 2s to slide from top, then does nothing in the following 14s, then fades. This is due to 80% and 90% blocks being exactly equal. What was this supposed to do instead?

Comment: Both images appear overlapped to me. I want the operator image to show 59s later but it shows with the first slideInLeft. I don't know if you can see both images are overlapped, can you?

Comment: To make the idea, delay is for the whole animation, not just a slide. Plus your 3rd and 4th slides do not differ, which means that the whole thing stays the same during that.

Comment: There is only one image in your fiddle. And it's not even existing (i had to put one i found on Google to see the result)

Comment: So what do I have to make them appear later?

Comment: Hmm I think I got it. I have to make a single CSS code for all my animations using Keyframes. I'll try it right now.

Comment: Can you describe the whole scene as you intended it to be?

Comment: I want the video to show up first with SlideInLeft effect with 30 secs delay then I want the image to appear with 50 secs delay but I can't. Both get overlapped.

Comment: Video and image should have different animation attributes but the same Keyframe can still do the trick if you want to animate them the same way. By example animation: slideInLeft4 2s linear 30s 1 normal both; for the video -  slideInLeft4 2s linear 50s 1 normal both; for the picture